# Document-free canvas for Web Worker

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web-worker

Is there any implementation of canvas without `document.createElement('canvas')`?

I want to work with canvas in web worker but i can't pass canvas data to it via `worker.postMessage()`, because canvas is HTMLElement.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), worker = new Worker('canvas.js');
worker.postMessage(canvas.getData());
```

Also i don't want to pass canvas's ImageData to web worker because i don't want to implement `context2d.drawImage()` manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Sorry, ImageData is your only recourse here.

Comment: do you know any implementations of context.drawImage() with getImageData()/putImageData()?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? putImageData() is essentially a drawImage() for ImageData. putImageData(myImageData, 0, 0); draws myImageData starting at 0,0.

Comment: Right, my question isn't clear enough. Say I have the source image 200x200 and the target image 100x100. I want to copy the source image over the target. With 2d-context it can be done with drawImage(). Are there any implementations of drawImage() with getImageData() + putImageData()?

Comment: You mean you want to put 200x200 ImageData on a 100x100 canvas? You'll have to make a 200x200 Canvas in memory, putImageData onto it, then drawImage the 200x200 Canvas onto the 100x100 canvas. If that doesnt make sense I can make an example.

Comment: No-no-no! This should be done in worker, so can't use drawImage(). I am talking about implementing drawImage() algorythm with getImageData/putImageData